# Is man really more similar to HaShem now or did the nachash just lie?

Tags: parashat-bereishit, gan-eden

The snake claimed that once you eat from the tree, ‘Your eyes will be opened, and you will be like God, knowing good and evil.'
The commentators (I believe the Ramchal) explain that before the sin evil was an external force represented in the nachash but once Adam & Chava consumed the fruit evil became an internal force & a part of our nature. So it would seem that Man was a lot more similar to HaShem before this episode, when evil was a completely separate entity.
Was the nachash just a liar or am I missing something?

Comment: Having more forces contained in you would seem to be more God-like. There's no force external to God.

Comment: On the simplest level, the distinction is being capable of containing two opposite, conflicting ideas or principles. This level of 'knowing G-d' is only possible post eating from the Tree of Knowledge of Tov and Ra.